# Can I dual boot windows 10 on an ssd and have a windows 10 install on an hdd

Tags: dualboot

I need to dual boot with windows already installed on the hdd and nothing on the ssd.

It’s an aspire v3 (i7 3610 16GB ram)
The hdd has really important files

Comment: You can dual boot however many installs you want by adding them to the BCD store from WinRE/WinPE via: `BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(you can technically do the same via `BCDedit`, however `BootRec` is simpler)_

Comment: Have you tried to research this yourself before asking?

Comment: @gronostaj although for you and me, this is a simple question, I do remember when I was less experienced and had similar questions. I did research but was unable to come to an answer myself that I dared to execute on my life install and wanted to make sure. In this case, I think the question is valid no matter what.

Comment: You need to have good backups on another drive. Also instructions will be different if UEFI or BIOS installs. UEFI requires gpt partitioning & then you need gpt on new drive also. But for Windows best to use Windows tools, and then for Linux use Linux tools. If you use Linux a lot, you may want both Windows & Linux on SSD and use HDD for data.https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/how-to-create-a-recovery-drive-for-reinstalling/58df9c7d-84de-4652-9952-8bac34abc6c5